# Best way to do a pagination on front end

Tags: pagination, paging, jquery-pagination, data-paging

I have a table that has a data for 30-60 rows. I would like to paginate this on front end. Basically something like:

```
First 1 2 3 4(<current) 5 6 .. 15(<last page) Last
```

jQuery would be the weapon for this I believe. Any good tutorials/advices how to do this? What to remember etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do everything on the client side, this plugin should do the trick very well: http://tablesorter.com

Comment: No but I dont wwant to do a sort, I just want to do pagination.. so that some of the rows get hidded and with paging usr can see them.

Comment: I know. This plugin also paginates http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html

Answer (score 0):

In angularJs, you may follow this approach as we do in Oodles Technologies,

Assume that their are 3000-4000 enties that you need to show with UI-select directive. usually if you bind more than 500 entries in select box or UI-select the website will get stucked for some time if you click on the select box or UI-select ,so how to solve this problem ?
Inorder to solve this problem you to two things:-
1. limitTo filter
2. A directive that alert controller that user has reached the bottom of list

Pagination in Ui select

```
<ui-select ng-model="education.clg" name="clg" theme="select2" append-to-body="true" sortable="true"  >
                  <ui-select-match placeholder="Select institution/university">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
                        <ui-select-choices repeat="college in colleges | propsFilter: {name: $select.search} >
                                 <div ng-bind-html="college.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
                  </ui-select-choices>
         </ui-select>
```

Now add limitTo filter in "ui-select-choices"

Now Create a directive that determine that user has reached down of list.

```
angular.module('app',[]).directive('scrollDetector', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var raw = element[0];
            element.bind('scroll', function () {
                if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
                  console.log("end of list");
                    scope.$apply(attrs.scrollDetector);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Lets use the above directive in ui-select. add scroll-detector=loadMore() in directive

```
 <ui-select-choices repeat="college in colleges | propsFilter: {name: $select.search} >
          <div ng-bind-html="college.name | highlight: $select.search" | limitTo:currentElement" scroll-detector="loadMore()">     </div>
         </ui-select-choices>
```

Now initialize currentElement in controller
$scope.currentElement=20;
Add loadMore() function in same controller

```
$scope.loadMore=function(){
  console.log("loadMore");
  $scope.currentElement=$scope.currentElement+20;
}
```

This will increment by 20 when user reach bottom of list. if you want to reset currrent element back to 20 if user click out side ui-select just use the below line to reset it back.

```
var myDiv=angular.element(document.querySelector('#myDiv'));
myDiv.click(function(){
  // reset back to 20
  $scope.currentElement=20;
})
```

Hope it helps